# What do the different PS button light signals mean?

Tags: ps-vita

I have a PS Vita and I keep it in sleep mode on my desk most of the time.

The PS button light is off most of the time, but I see the PS button turning on often.

I know orange means charging, but once in a while it will flash a few times then turn off again, at first I thought it means I had a notification but turning the screen on shows nothing.

Is there a guide somewhere which explains the different signals?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As seen [here](http://news.cnet.com/8301-17938_105-57373522-1/ps-vita-gets-video-maps-and-blinking-lights/), different lights display different power states or notifications.

- Solid blue: Plugged in
- Flashing blue: Standby mode
- Slow blue flash: Unread message or information
- Solid orange: Charging, but powered off
- Flashing orange: Battery is going to call it quits soon

There's also the so called BFLOD (Blue Flashing Light of Death) that indicates a problem with the vita itself. You can resort to the initialization menu you get by pressing the power button for 30 seconds and trying the different options there.

Comment: I also have mine now switching between a blue and a purple light? What does this mean?

Comment: @user76434 Purple light is a new one... you might want to have a tech to take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

The Blue light simply means it is on
Pulsing blue means that there is a message or notification. Blinking rapidly can mean either the BFLOD or and urgent notification, such as a party or game invite.
Orange means charging, and when plugged in and blinking orange, means the battery's' charge is too low to operate. Give it five to ten minutes if it does this.

Comment: This doesn't add anything other than what's in the accepted answer